# Dart: How to get a list of package's variables, functions, etc.?

Tags: dart

In python there is `dir` function that lists methods and variables of modules and classes. How to do the same in Dart?

I have to check whether a certain variable exists in an imported package. I tried to wrap it with try-catch block, but it crashes on compile-time with the following output:

```
ex_01_test.dart:9:19: Error: Getter not found: 'obj'.
    print(student.obj);
```

Comment: You would have to use reflection for something like that. Look into the mirrors package. That being said, reflection should be used sparingly. See if there are other ways to achieve the functionality you want without checking for the existence of variables at runtime. Also notably, the mirrors package is not available on flutter if you are building a flutter app.

Answer (score 1):

Your IDE should already be informing you that something doesn't exist, as you discovered.  There's no "runtime check" for this, as Dart is fully compiled before executing a single line.

Comment: That last part of your answer regarding compilation is inaccurate. The Dart specification does not specify the time of compilation. Whether it is fully compiled before execution or not is up to the implementation.

Comment: And when there's a viable alternate implementation of Dart, suddenly your comment will make sense.  I'm talking about the current, and foreseeable future Dart ecosystem.

Comment: Even the official Dart compiler does not use full ahead-of-time compilation by default. Much of one's code is JIT compiled.